# spilt .csv file and insert to excel

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I'm having difficulties understanding the best way to go about this, as title suggests I have a csv file that I would like to split, copying a row into separate worksheets based on the first value of each line.

My csv file looks (first column/value) like this

Fruit

Veg

Meat

Fruit

Veg

Meat

I simply want all the Fruits, veg and meat rows to be it is own worksheet within a workbook.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried ? are you getting an error ? please post your current source code and point out which lines or steps are missing or not behaving as expected

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking using a loop + case-switch statement

```
int rownumber=0;
int rowoffset=0;

for (int rownumber = 0; rownumber < endoffile; i++)
{

    rowoffset=rownumber%3;

        switch (rowoffset)
        {
            case 0:
                //insert into fruit CSV or worksheet
                break;
            case 1:
                //insert into veg CSV or worksheet
                break;
            case 2:
                //insert into meat CSV or worksheet
                break;
        }

}
```

or something like that (code untested, but the general idea is there)

Comment: what would you suggest are the best ways read the csv and then insert into excel?

Comment: @ManWithNoName to read a file TEXT file line by line use this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In Excel (depending on version) look for option that says import data or import external data and run for the wizard with your CSV file.

Comment: I have to do this programatiically

Comment: I see.  Try using streamwriter, streamreader and string builder methods.  Technically speaking from your code thats not CSV.  CSV would be comma-separated values, while gives you a delimiter you can use to manipulate strings.  In any case good luck with it.